# Get-WmiObject with credential fails when within Start-Job scriptblock

Tags: powershell, start-job

I am successfully retrieving some information from Windows 2000 machines using the Get-WmiObjet cmdlet. These machines are not part of our domain so I am using the -Credential parameter to pass local administrator credentials.

I am now trying to run several WMI queries in parallel using Start-Job but I can't get even one query to work.

When I run the following:

```
Start-Job -initializationscript {$cred = get-credential -credential administrator}  -scriptblock {gwmi win32_computersystem -ComputerName 10.1.2.3 -Credential $cred}
```

a job is created, I am prompted for the credentials, but the job never completes, its state is always "Running".

Of course:

```
C:\>$cred = Get-Credential -credential administrator
C:\>gwmi win32_computersystem -ComputerName 10.1.2.3 -Credential $cred
```

works just fine.

How do I get Get-WmiObject to run successfully within Start-Job with alternate credentials?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential Administrator
Start-Job -scriptblock {Param ($cred) gwmi win32_computersystem -ComputerName 10.1.2.3 -Credential $cred} -ArgumentList $cred
```

Looks like the background job is blocked for input and has been running forever for that reason.

Comment: Also the reason I didnt' try to use -ArgumentList is because the help is misleading. I found out that a bug has been submitted via Microsoft Connect:

Comment: Link to the bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/563695/argumentlist-parameter-to-start-job-incomplete

Comment: For the sake of completeness, this question had been answered before on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691612/make-a-powershell-function-task-run-in-the-background